# How to Convert SQL Server NVARCHAR(3000) to Oracle NCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql, type-conversion

I need to query tables in SQL Server from Oracle via database links. One of the SQL Server tables I need to query has a `NVARCHAR` column with a max length of 3000 characters. Oracle treats that as a `LONG` datatype so trying to use `TO_NCHAR` so that I can read the values returns the following error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent data types: expected NCHAR got NLONG

Is there a way in Oracle, using SQL or PL/SQL, to get the value, or at most the first 2000 characters, from the `NVARCHAR(3000)` column?

Comment: Why LONG and not CLOB?

Comment: I gave that a shot this morning using TO_NCLOB, but received the following error: 

ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables

Comment: try CAST(column_name  AS NVARCHAR2(3000))

Comment: I don't know what I am talking about, so take that into consideration... Instead of accessing "remote_variable" and doing something to it in Oracle, wouldn't it make more sense to apply some transformation (like truncating the value to something like 2000 characters and then applying the equivalent of `to_nchar` on it), all on the SQL Server side, and THEN accessing the result?

Comment: @schurik - I got this error when I tried the CAST with 3000 characters:  ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype  
I tried 2000 characters, but still to no avail:  
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NLONG

Comment: @mathguy We've used that approach in the past by converting the values in SQL Server views that we can query from Oracle. I was hoping that there would be a direct approach I could use in Oracle

Comment: I didn't mean create a whole view for this; I meant in a function call, formula, whatever. In my mind I see three steps, always in this order; the first and/or third are optional. 1. Process the data on the SQL Server side. 2. call the result from Oracle. 3 further process in Oracle. Something like 'xyz' || "import from SQL Server(left("value", 2000)). left("value", 2000) is a sort of truncation on the SQL Server side; whatever "calls" this value out of SQL Server on behalf of Oracle should call this processed value, not the stored one.

Comment: @mathguy I agree with your approach and I would normally follow that it. This is one of the special situations where the more work that can be done in Oracle, the better. If it's extraordinarily difficult to do something like this in Oracle, it's not too big of a deal. But if it can be done, that would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately once Oracle stamps a value as LONG there isn't much you can do with it. You can convert LONG (NLONG) to CLOB (NCLOB), which would be much better, but only as part of an INSERT statement.

Comment: migrate using 12c - it supports 32k VARCHAR2's - and don't use NVARCHAR2 - just set your database to be UTF-8 or equivalent and you get unicode support by default

Answer (score -1):

If  you  need  to  declare  a  variable-length  string,  you  must provide  the  maximum  length of  that 
string. For example, the VARCHAR2 data type. The following example illustrates declaring and 
using some string variables:

```
DECLARE
name varchar2(20);
```